# Servicestack Embedding Javascript Resources

Tags: razor, servicestack, mef

I have been working on an MEF/Servicestack based framework for an SaaS product. I am compiling razor views into external modules that are loaded during runtime with MEF. I am struggling trying to embed javascript resources into the dlls and then referencing them successfully when the view is loaded. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Could you please expand with details of what you are doing, and of how your approach is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section on [Embedded Resources in Virtual File System wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#embedded-resources) explains the Embedded Resources support in more detail where you just need to ensure the Assembly that contains your embedded resources is defined in either the `Config.EmbeddedResourceSources` Assembly list or `Config.EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes` types list, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
   EmbeddedResourceSources = { typeof(TypeInDllWithEmbeddedResources).Assembly },
   EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes = { typeof(TypeInDllWithEmbeddedResources) } 
});
```

However typically **no configuration is needed** as the top-level Assembly where your `AppHost` is defined is automatically pre-registered and as it's also typically the same Assembly where your Website resources are maintained, any embedded resources in that Assembly are automatically available. E.g. if you have an embedded resource in your project at `/dir/file.js` it would be available from the same path where ServiceStack is mounted, e.g `http://localhost:1337/dir/file.js`.

#### Specifying an Embedded Resource in VS.NET

You just need to make the file an Embedded Resource by setting the **Build Action** in the File property panel in VS.NET to **Embedded Resource** so that it gets compiled as an embedded resource in your Website .dll.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate the detail. Does this have to be done early during the initial call to Configure or can I edit the config during runtime? Ideally I want to update these sources whenever MEF reloads.

Comment: @ticky74 Specifying an embedded file needs to be done at development time so the compiler can embed the file in the .dll.